# Derive the explicit expression of the Chebyshev polynimial: $T_n(x) =n\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-2)^{k}{\frac {(n+k-1)!}{(n-k)!(2k)!}}(1-x)^{k}$.

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

The explicit expression for the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind is given as follows.
$$
T_n(x) =n\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-2)^{k}{\frac {(n+k-1)!}{(n-k)!(2k)!}}(1-x)^{k}\qquad n>0
$$
However, no proof of this expression is available in any literature. Can anyone please provide the proof for this equation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The usual recurrence for Chebyshev is 
$$ T_{n+1}(x) + T_{n-1}(x) = 2 x T_n(x), \quad T_0(x) = 1, \quad T_1(x) = x. \tag{1} $$
Consider the polynomial sequence
$$ f_n(t) := \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n+k-1)!\, n}{(n-k)!\,(2k)!}t^k, \qquad f_0(t) := 1. \tag{2} $$
We can prove it satisfies the recursion
$$ f_{n+1}(t) + f_{n-1}(t) = (2+t)f_n(x). \tag{3} $$
The method is to compare coefficients of $\,t^k\,$ using
the identity
$$ \frac{(n+k)(n+k-1)(n+1)}{(n+1-k)(n-k)} + (n-1) =\\
\frac{(n+k-1)(2n)}{(n-k)} + \frac{(2k)(2k-1)n}{(n+1-k)(n-k)}. \tag{4} $$
Finally, notice that if $\,2+t=2x\,$ then $\,1+t/2=x\,$ and therefore
$\, T_n(x) = f_n(t).\,$

The idea is that the usual Chebyshev polynomials satisfy
$$ |T_n(x)| \le 1 \qquad \text{ if } \quad -1\le x \le 1 \tag{5} $$
while the related polynomials satisfy
$$ |f_n(t)| \le 1 \qquad \text{ if } \quad -4\le x \le 0.\tag{6} $$
and so their domains are shifted and scaled differently.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you give any reference for the polynomial sequence $f_n(t)$ and its recursion relation ?

Comment: @OrkodipMookherjee I just used your explicit expression summation and simplified it only using powers of $t$ instead of $x$.